# Setting up Amazon CloudFront with an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

What would be the simplest way to associate a CloudFront distribution with an EC2 server?

Public IP/DNS keeps changing as I shutdown/start the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to associate an [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).